# Efficiency improvement: Join on multiple Period_ID from multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like a more efficient solution to my query setup.

Right now I have a base table with Period_ID's of the form YYYYMM. Basically I want to join to the same table, in addition to several other tables, on each of the last 12 Period_ID's. Right now I create the base table along with the last 12 Period_ID's (current periodid=202307, periodid1moBefore=202306 etc), and then join back to the table (and others) on each of the last 12 Period_ID's so that I can bring in data for the last 12 months in the same table. Example below (this would be for one of my tables, I have several):

- Z.periodid1moBefore = B.periodid
- Z.periodid2moBefore = B.periodid
- ...
- Z.periodid11moBefore = B.periodid
- Z.periodid12moBefore = B.periodid

I have tables of the form:

| PeriodID | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 202205 | $100 |
| 202206 | $150 |
| 202207 | $30 |
| ... | ... |
| 202305 | $60 |
| 202306 | $80 |
| 202307 | $120 |

I want a table like the below:

| Sales | Sales_1mo_ago | Sales_2mo_ago | ... | Sales_12mo_ago |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $120 | $80 | $60 | ... | $30 |

I don't have a definition of "more efficient" but the way I am doing it currently, with 6 tables and 12 months of join, that is 72 left joins that I am doing. I feel like there has to be a better way.

Comment: Please update your question with definitions of your source table(s), sample data, the result you are trying to achieve and the query you’ve managed to write so far. What is your definition of a more efficient solution?

Comment: I have updated my question to include more info

Comment: This often done using a calendar table with helper columns. As an eample a helper column called `PeriodOffset` which contains 0 for 202307, -1 for 202306, -2 for 202305 etc. These values are maintained by a daily job. Looks like you already have this table but no helper columns. Can you clarify in your question for the table aliases `Z` and `B`, which is your transaction table and which is your calendar table?

Answer (score 0):

So if your data is dense, and each month is always present, and only once. You can avoid the joins and use LAG

so a CTE with some example data

```
with example_data(periodid, sales) as (
    select * from values
    (202205,    100),
    (202206,    150),
    (202207,    30),
    (202208,    38),
    (202209,    39),
    (202210,    40),
    (202211,    41),
    (202212,    42),
    (202301,    51),
    (202302,    52),
    (202303,    53),
    (202304,    54),
    (202305,    60),
    (202306,    80),
    (202307,    120)
)
```

and then the main code:

```
select periodid
    ,sales
    ,lag(sales, 1) over (order by periodid) as sales_1mo_ago   
    ,lag(sales, 2) over (order by periodid) as sales_2mo_ago   
    ,'...' as "..."
    --,lag(sales, 3) over (order by periodid) as sales_3mo_ago
    --,lag(sales, 4) over (order by periodid) as sales_4mo_ago   
    --,lag(sales, 5) over (order by periodid) as sales_5mo_ago   
    --,lag(sales, 6) over (order by periodid) as sales_6mo_ago
    --,lag(sales, 7) over (order by periodid) as sales_7mo_ago   
    --,lag(sales, 8) over (order by periodid) as sales_8mo_ago   
    --,lag(sales, 9) over (order by periodid) as sales_9mo_ago
    --,lag(sales, 10) over (order by periodid) as sales_10mo_ago
    --,lag(sales, 11) over (order by periodid) as sales_11mo_ago
    ,lag(sales, 12) over (order by periodid) as sales_12mo_ago
from example_data
order by 1 desc;
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Is this window function method computationally less expensive than joining on each of the 12 periodid's?

Comment: Yes, for large tables the once sorted the window functions are near free. Aka the sort has a cost. But it should be easy to test for improvement on a reasonable sized dataset. I tend to try idea’s and check they make a difference. From there general rules can be made. But there is no true one rule. Otherwise the SQL optimizer would already do it for “all code”